# how to hide INFO in cells outputs in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, pycaret

[image: pycaret]

How do I hide info in output cells in Google Colab and only show the result of the code and not the INFO lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Colab issue. What you are seeing is the output from Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module that is produced inside the `pycaret` library's code. You can turn it off by setting the logging level of the specific library to a level higher than `INFO`, by running these lines before your `pycaret` code:

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("pycaret").setLevel(logging.WARNING)  # see docs for other logging levels
```

or [disabling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.disable) logging altogether with

```
logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
```